# Don't impose delay loading Close dialog when you haven't just loaded it

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, live-refresh

Because of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284783/the-new-post-modification-notification-constantly-messes-up-editing), clicking the "close" link on a question that's been edited (for me usually the edit comes in a half-second before, as I'm reaching for the link) reloads the question instead of opening the Close dialog. Clicking it *again* to actually open the close dialog says

> You may only open the Close dialog every three seconds

I didn't open it, I refreshed the post.

And yes, there are lots of times when the post edit is so trivial it's obvious in less than a second that it doesn't affect the need to close the question.

Comment: Another reason to "open" the dialog twice in a row:  when it failed to load the first time due to a bad connection.

Comment: ^^ e.g., it should only trigger the rate limiting when it did actually open.

Comment: I've never understood the purpose of this limit. I found [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172706/349538) about it on Meta, but it doesn't have any answer.